# Is there a way to define a custom domain on Route53 for a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-functions, amazon-route53, cname

I've created on Google Cloud Platform a new service with the help of the Serverless framework.
The service contains a Cloud Function that provides a GC url:

```
https://europe-west3-service-12345.cloudfunctions.net/endpoint
```

We would like to use our own DNS, let's say acme.com, with our own SSL certificate so we can access to:

```
https://service.acme.com/endpoint
```

Our DNS hosted zone is managed on AWS Route 53.

I've tried to naively create a CNAME to associate `service.acme.com` to `europe-west3-service-12345.cloudfunctions.net` but it ends by an error 404 from Google when accessing to `https://service.acme.com/endpoint`

Comment: There's nothing really you can do on the AWS side (other than writing code to proxy all requests to the function), since the SSL cert for hosting the function needs to live on the Google side.  You can use Firebase Hosting to set up a vanity domain for your function that does this proxying internally.